# Understanding encryption with base64 and mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption, base64, urlencode

i need to pass a GET string to an email to allow a user to access specific booking details.
i.e. /bookingconformation.php?bookingID=123.

I am trying to encrypt the bookingID with base64 (**edit** and mcrypt) (in the hope that it will be nearly impossible to guess and access other users booking details (although the booking details are not really too sensitive!)). This is so that only the intended user can access the booking conformation.

I am using code found mostly on here (stackOverflow), as i am far from an encryption expert!!

I have a few issues.
The code i am using is below and below this is the list of issues i am having

```
/**
    * a basic encryption for things like IDs, so links can be created and emailed to i.e booking details
    * @param int/str $x what is to be encrypted
    * @ENCRYPTION_KET str the encyption key
    * @return encrypted string
    */
    public static function basicEncrypt($x, $ENCRYPTION_KET) {
        $key = pack('H*', $ENCRYPTION_KET);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $x, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;
        $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);
        $encrypted_x = urlencode($ciphertext_base64);
        return $encrypted_x;
    }

    /**
    * a basic de-cryption for things like IDs, so links can be created and emailed to i.e booking details
    * @param str $x what is to be de-crypted
    * @ENCRYPTION_KET str the encyption key
    * @return decrypted string
    */
    public static function basicDecrypt($x, $ENCRYPTION_KET) {      
        $x = urldecode($x);     
        $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($x);        
        $key = pack('H*', $ENCRYPTION_KET);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);
        $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);
        $de_crypted_x = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);
        return $de_crypted_x;       
    }
```

**Issue 1 :** using basicEncrypt() gives a different encryption string each time i use it (i.e for the same bookingID of 123). 
As long as it decrypts to the same though, it does not matter if the encryption string is different each time. If anyone can let me know if this should return a different string each time and i would also be grateful if an (easy to understand) explanation can be given as to why this is?

**Issue 2 :**
The above code works MOST of the time.... (maybe 80%) but other times it does not decrypt to the correct answer... i dont understand why :-(. if anyone can let me know what i am doing wrong so that it works 100% of the time i would be very grateful!

**Issue 3 : (possible issue)**
i am using urlencode() and urldecode(). I have read lots on stackOverflow and can not work out if i should be using this or not! I suspect **issue 2** may be caused by this, but can not seen to work out the correct way of then doing this and being URL safe. I have tried replacing the URLencode with something similar to the below (found on here), but this then causes the above to work 0% of the time

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
 return strtr($input, '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
 return strtr($input, '-_,', '+/=');
}
```

**Also** is the method i am using to allow the user to see their booking details OK/advisable? (as mentioned the data is not really sensitive, it only includes the users name, booking REF and what was booked. ID needs to be shown when the user turns up for the (hotel) booking).

Any help in allowing me to understand what i am doing (and encryption) a little better is much appreciated or even more appreciated if anyone can point out (so that i may correct) the errors in my method would be great!!

Thanks for looking at this :-)
Ford

Comment: @CharlotteDunois  basee64_decode doesn't "decrypt" (as you know)... it decodes.    Ford:   issue1 is not an issue..   a random "initialization vector" is used each time... resulting in different crypttext

Comment: @BradKent and otherPosters, i now see what it is different... simple really, but i didn't spot it until it was pointed out :-)

Comment: You might make your life a lot easier if you used [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If anyone can let me know if this should return a different string
>   each time and...to why this is?

The encryption result is determined by the encryption key, the clear text, and the initialization vector (iv).  The iv is randomly built every time you encrypt as a result of this line:

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
```

So the result is also different every time.

> The above code works MOST of the time.... (maybe 80%) but other times
>   it does not decrypt to the correct answer

I don't know what that's about. url encoding/decoding should be sufficient; I don't think base64 encoding is needed. Just be sure to do it in the right order: encrypt first, then encode when writing. Decode first then decrypt when reading.

> I am trying to encrypt the bookingID with base64 (in the hope that it
>   will be nearly impossible to guess and access other users booking
>   details...is the method i am using to allow the user to see their
>   booking details OK

A better approach would be to require authentication.  You can leave the booking ID unencrypted, but protect the user by requiring username & pass before you show the booking details

> i agree authentication is better, but i also need to allow for
>   non-registered users

I would use a keyed hash, and include both the booking ID and the hash in the url. It will then be easy to know when a user is trying to access another's booking.

Setting the URL:

```
//hash will always be the same for the same booking id, but impossible to guess
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256',$bookingID,$SECRET_KEY);

//url includes both the booking id and the hash
$url = "http://example.com/confirm.php?id=$bookingID&sig=$hash";
```

Before showing booking details, make sure that the hash is correct:

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'],$_GET['sig'])){
    http_response_code(400); //tells the browser that the request is malformed
    echo "Missing booking id or signature";
    exit;
}
$bookingID = $_GET['id'];
$sig = $_GET['sig'];
$correct_hash = hash_hmac('sha256',$bookingID,$SECRET_KEY);

//if anyone modifies the url, the sig will not equal the correct hash
if($sig!==$correct_hash){
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Invalid signature";
    exit;
}
//we get here if the sig matched the booking ID. Show booking details
```

Using this technique you can add more info in the URL, such as an `expires` parameter that will cause the request to be denied if someone clicks the link after too much time has gone by. To ensure that no one altered the link, just include all the parameters in the signature:

```
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256',"$bookingID.$expires",$SECRET_KEY);
```

When you check the signature by building a new hash, make sure to include the same parameters in the same order

Comment: thank you! i agree authentication is better, but i also need to allow for non-registered users (i have already done it with authentication but need this method too :-( )

Comment: @Ford I've added a section at the end of my answer to show you what I would do if authentication was not an option.

Comment: @Ford let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you, your hash_hmac suggestion works great :-).

Comment: @Ford Cool. Did you decide to include any parameter in the url besides the booking ID? If so did you remember to use all parameters in the hash?

Answer (score 3):

First, `base64()` has nothing to do with encrypting, it's a type of encoding and should not be used for any kind of protection. Please don't use these terms in the same sentence!

The reason the encryption is providing a different output each time is that you are using a random IV for each encryption.

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
```

Why is there a problem with having the user be authenticated when they hit the booking confirmation endpoint? They could visit `/bookingconfirmation.php?bookingID=123` and either already be authenticated or have to login to view the booking. This seems like the best and most secure option. The ID in the URL is also no longer a problem as you can verify it against the user.

Alternatively, you could tie a random ID to the booking that is sufficiently random/strong enough to prevent a brute force attack, coupled with rate limiting on the endpoint, if you don't want to have the user be authenticated.

```
$randomToken = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

You would then use the random token to fetch the booking instead of the booking ID, `/bookingconfirmation.php?bookingID=$randomToken`. This is a better and easier approach than encrypting the booking ID in the URL.

Comment: thank you, much appreciated. i am also authenticating some users, but registration is optional, so i need to allow none registered members access too. thank you for your answer, it sounds a good solution!

Comment: Ah then yes, if the user can make a booking without registration you will need some other method. I should add then, if you go down the route of creating a random token for each booking to retrieve them, they can't be accessible via the sequential ID, or an attacker could still walk them.

Comment: thank you. i think i understyand (/bookingconformation.php?bookingID=123 would not return any results (as it would decrypt "123" to something wrong)). or as you say, i only match on the randomToken. if this is what you mean?